# Run VBScript as Administrator and Wait for completion

Tags: windows, vbscript, admin

I can't find a definite solution to this problem. In short, what I want to do is gather a list of applications installed on the computer, and write it to a file. Here was my first attempt:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
randTrashVar = objShell.Run("cmd /c wmic product get Name,Version > " & strAppListPath, 0, true)
```

But it must be run as an admin to work in all my cases. So I tried wrapping it in runas, but don't know too much about it so I could be wrong there.

```
randTrashVar = objShell.Run("runas /user:Administrator ""cmd /c wmic product get Name,Version > " & strAppListPath & "", 0, true)
```

Or doing something with `objShell.Exec` too

```
Set getAppsProcess = objShell.Exec("runas /user:Administrator ""cmd /c wmic product get Name,Version > " & strAppListPath & "")
Do While getAppsProcess.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

The first one gets me somewhere, and they all wait for the command to finish before moving on, but didn't run as admin/run at all (as far as I know).

This runs as Admin now, but no wait

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "cmd", "/c wmic product get Name,Version > " & strAppListPath, "", "runas", 1
```

What can I do to get the best of these?

Comment: Two scripts willo work of course, the first calling the second as admin. `Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Product")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.Name & " " & objItem.Version
Next`

Answer (score 0):

One or the other. WMIC does not require admin necessarly - •

**wmic**

The first time you run Wmic after system installation, it must be run from an elevated command prompt. The elevated mode may not be required for subsequent executions of Wmic unless the WMI operations require administrator privilege. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa826699(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa826699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). Type for table format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:htable
```

or in a form format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:hform
```

It will create a html file on the desktop.

Note

This is not a full list. This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

or in a file

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUninstall.txt"
```

To see it in notepad in a different format

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type Regedit and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Right click the Uninstall key and choose Export. If you save as a reg file (there is also text file, they are slightly different text formats) you need to right click the file and choose Edit to view it.

To view Windows Updates

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUpdate.html" qfe  get /format:htable
```

### .

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm liking the output of your first command, but how would I call it from VBScript? BTW, I thought I needed to be Admin because I got an error on one computer occurring on that line saying something about permission